# WebKit CoreIPC exception on bad access when booting (my build)

Tags: webkit

I get BAD_ACCESS signal when WebKit calls CoreIPC open on ASSERT(m_receivePort). I am running under XCODE using WebKit2. The call to open comes from a call to didFinishLaunching.

Any ideas where to start looking for source? I'm new to WebKit.-

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if the app runs fine without XCode.
- You may have had some experiments building WebKit. Clean the output directory and build from scratch.
- Try building Debug instead of Release (or vice versa.)
- Try updating WebKit from svn - some revisions may contain crashy behavior.

That's it for now...

Comment: I had the lastest build, so I just deleted WebKitBuild and ran Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --debug It seems to work perfectly. The previous build I did manually using XCode for all the parts. I guess there is something missing when you do that. Too bad. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the matter is that there is a lot of generated code that sometimes does not get re-generated when the relevant code units change, that is the culprit to look out for in the future.